# How can I create multiple matrices or dataframes from a list in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, matrix

I have a list like this:

```
[[1]]
[1] "Vigia"                      "PA"                         "1508209"                   
[4] "Viseu"                      "PA"                         "1508308"                   

[[2]]
[1] "Abaetetuba"                 "PA"                         "1500107"                   
[4] "Acara"                      "PA"                         "1500206"
```

and I want to make two matrices like this:

```
                           [,1]                       [,2]                          [,3] 
[1,]                      Vigia                         PA                       1508209
[2,]                      Viseu                         PA                       1508308

                           [,1]                       [,2]                          [,3] 
[1,]                 Abaetetuba                         PA                       1500107
[2,]                      Acara                         PA                       1508308
```

I've tried to use

```
for(i in 1:2){
  output[i] <- matrix(unlist(A[[i]]), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
}
```

But it's not working. I also tried to transform that list to a dataframe, but I couldn't.

Comment: Please share the output of  ```dput(head(your_list, 2))```.

Comment: `lapply(A, function(x) matrix(x, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE))` ?

Comment: It's almost that! But I want to transform each A[[i]] into a matrix, outside the list. How can I make this?

Answer (score 0):

## Edit:

corrected my answer so it uses a loop:

```
li <- list(c( "Vigia", "PA", "1508209", "Viseu", "PA", "1508308"),
           c("Abaetetuba", "PA", "1500107", "Acara", "PA", "1500206"))

output <- list()
for(i in seq_along(li)){
  output[[i]] <- matrix(li[[i]], nrow=2, byrow = TRUE)
}

output[[1]]
```

> ```
>      [,1]    [,2] [,3]     
> [1,] "Vigia" "PA" "1508209"
> [2,] "Viseu" "PA" "1508308"
> ```

```
output[[2]]
```

> ```
>      [,1]         [,2] [,3]     
> [1,] "Abaetetuba" "PA" "1500107"
> [2,] "Acara"      "PA" "1500206"
> ```

But we have to be aware that matrices can only have one data type, which means in this case that everything is going to be a string!